# Chrome Extension - Shorten URL from the Context Menu?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons, url-shortening

Does anyone know of a chrome extension to shorten a URL from the context menu? i.e. Right clicking anywhere on the page and creating/copying the link?

I have switched to Chrome and the tinyUrl plugin does this for FF.

Thanks,

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you've searched on https://chrome.google.com/extensions for "url shortening" and haven't found what you need?

Comment: Yes. I dont want to click the icon in the corner to shorten the URL, I want to do it from the context menu - right clicking anywhere on the page and clicking an option from the menu there. Lots of FF extensions do this.....

Comment: I did the search and didn't come up with anything. 4.0 hasn't been public for that long, so one might come along eventually. Is there a place you can make suggestions for features on one of the existing ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ecehogjcciopmihcocdchiaciibinajf?hl=en-US

Comment: Amazing - just what I was looking for. Thanks Matt.